# API for disable inactive users in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, user, deactivate

I wanted to know if there is any API that allows me to deactivate users in marketing cloud when they have been inactive for 60 days, any information is useful

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the built in [security setting](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_security_settings.htm&type=5) for this?

> The Login Expires After Inactivity setting prevents a user from logging in to the account after not logging in for several days. For example, if the value is 90 days and a user doesn’t log in for 90 days, you must reset the user login information. This setting helps prevent unauthorized users from exploiting old accounts.

Comment: This would be the same as deactivating users from the admin setup interface ?

Comment: This feature in security settings doesn't appear to change the users Enabled flag to No.

It will only prevent the user from logging in, and require them to reset their password to the registered email address on file or contact the Marketing Cloud Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

The [Security Setting](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_security_settings.htm&type=5) should always be enabled by default, to prevent old logins from being used.

> The Login Expires After Inactivity setting prevents a user from logging in to the account after not logging in for several days. For example, if the value is 90 days and a user doesn’t log in for 90 days, you must reset the user login information. This setting helps prevent unauthorized users from exploiting old accounts.

If you are trying to automate this for license purpose, you can use the [SOAP Web Service API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/web_service_guide.html) (As a REST API does not exist for this function) to [Retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/retrieve.html)/[Update](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/update.html) the [AccountUser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/accountuser.html) object